# How can I store truffles?

Tags: storage-method, truffles

My husband will bring home some fresh white truffles from Italy. I never had truffles in my kitchen and I don't know how to store them. Any advice?

**Subquestion suggested by casperOne:** It would be interesting to hear answers both about long-term storage in the kitchen *and* storage options for transporting them on a long flight.

Comment: "Migrated from stackoverflow.com", now that's a banner I never thought I'd see here. @casperOne, awesome.

Comment: And the related SO meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157678/truffles-programming-are-they-related#157678

Comment: How long are you wanting to store them for? This can make a difference in method of storage.

Comment: @derobert Same here, which is exactly why I did it.  We thought it was spam, see here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157723/140951

Comment: @rumtscho Would it be out of line to edit the question to indicate how to store them during transport, or would that affect the existing answer too much (if the husband is bringing them home from Italy, *he* should have a proper way to bring them as well).

Comment: @casperOne we have had users complaining that somebody "put words in their mouth" and reversing an edit which expanded a question beyond its original scope. But your point is very relevant, so I guess we can do the edit if we clearly mark it as not done by the OP. Alternatively, we could make that a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

You can store fresh truffles in a kitchen towel and close it in a glass jar. Here (http://www.truffle-shop.com/storing-truffles) I even read that you can store the truffle with rice or eggs. The perfume will penetrate the egg shell and later you can eat truffle scrambled eggs without putting truffles on :-)

Comment: I can verify that the egg trick works. Haven't tried it with white truffles though, only the cheaper black variety. Presumably it works even better with white truffles since they are much stronger in flavour (supposedly).

Comment: I've seen the dry rice method before, keeps them dry and protects them from getting crushed while keeping airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is something that is airtight. If you're within reach of a vacuum packager, I think that putting a folded paper towel in the base of the bag and placing the truffles on top and sealing under a snug vacuum will keep them freshest the longest. Like any other fungus you don't want to expose them to much moisture.  Don't wash them until your ready to use them.

http://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/vegetables/truffle-glossary4.asp#storing

Comment: This would store the truffles in anaerobic conditions, promoting botulism growth as @rumtscho pointed out in the answer I deleted, because the reference I found included storing the truffles under oil

Comment: I see nothing wrong with vacuum sealing them to keep them fresh. The original question states nothing about the length of time they need to be stored. If it's long term storage, vacuum packaging and then freezing is a recommended method.

Comment: The information in the link says that they will keep fresh for 2-3 days. While this may be true, my experience with black truffles is that you should eat them as soon as possible. I actually tried buying white truffles from a shop in Berlin once (I live in Sweden). This was on a Friday, and I told the woman behind the counter that I would not be able to eat them until Sunday evening, and could she please vacuum pack them for me. In the end she refused to sell me any, saying that it would be a waste unless I ate them on that same Friday evening. :)